# JavaScript ECMA script derived grammar error

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a simplified grammar derived from the ECMA Script grammar:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/ecmascript/ECMAScript.g4

The original grammar works fine so far and I added a few rules only. However the following expression is a valid expression in my grammar but throws an error in the original ECMA grammar:

```
round(frames++/((getTime()-start)/1000))
```

caused by the

> frames++/

expression.

Whereas the following similar expressions works:

```
round(frames++*((getTime()-start)/1000))
round(frames++%((getTime()-start)/1000))
```

My question is how can I make the first expression work and what is the difference?

Comment: You wrote the first expression works already with your grammar and then you ask how to make it work. That doesn't make much sense. To say something about the differences would require that we can doma diff between the original grammar und yours.

Comment: Dear Mike thanks for the reply. The grammar is not finished yet but will be much simplier than the ECMA grammar. Let me ask differently. Why does the expression "round(frames++/((getTime()-start)/1000))" in the ECMA grammar not work although the other cited expressions work? What do I have to change in the ECMA grammar to make this expression work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because the `/` is interpreted as the start of a regex delimiter.

If you look at the lexer-method that determines when a `/` is a regex literal and when a division operator:

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} iff the lexer can match a regex literal.
 *
 * @return {@code true} iff the lexer can match a regex literal.
 */
private boolean isRegexPossible() {

    if (this.lastToken == null) {
        // No token has been produced yet: at the start of the input,
        // no division is possible, so a regex literal _is_ possible.
        return true;
    }

    switch (this.lastToken.getType()) {
        case Identifier:
        case NullLiteral:
        case BooleanLiteral:
        case This:
        case CloseBracket:
        case CloseParen:
        case OctalIntegerLiteral:
        case DecimalLiteral:
        case HexIntegerLiteral:
        case StringLiteral:
            // After any of the tokens above, no regex literal can follow.
            return false;
        default:
            // In all other cases, a regex literal _is_ possible.
            return true;
    }
}
```

then this should also return false for the tokens `--` and `++`.

Adjust the `isRegexPossible()` as follows:

```
private boolean isRegexPossible() {

    if (this.lastToken == null) {
        // No token has been produced yet: at the start of the input,
        // no division is possible, so a regex literal _is_ possible.
        return true;
    }

    switch (this.lastToken.getType()) {
        case Identifier:
        case NullLiteral:
        case BooleanLiteral:
        case This:
        case CloseBracket:
        case CloseParen:
        case OctalIntegerLiteral:
        case DecimalLiteral:
        case HexIntegerLiteral:
        case StringLiteral:
        case PlusPlus:               // <-- NEW
        case MinusMinus:             // <-- NEW
            // After any of the tokens above, no regex literal can follow.
            return false;
        default:
            // In all other cases, a regex literal _is_ possible.
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much for your time help. Now it works

Comment: No problemo @Marcel.

Comment: Would be good if that change would also make it into the ECMA grammar on Github.

Comment: @Marcel I just saw the original grammar already had `PlusPlus` and `MinusMinus` tokens.

Comment: @Bart Yes, I noticed that. Thanks again